# Detect specific string including wildcards and isolate wildcards in PLPGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Is it possible in PostgreSQL 9.4 (PLPGSQL) to detect if a string contains a certain string including wildcards and get the wildcards, ex.:

```
IF NEW.my_string CONTAINS 'patternXYZ' THEN
    NEW.my_values := getXYZ(my_string)
END IF;
```

Which would result in NEW.my_values to contain XYZ (which can be anything in the string, but only the 3 characters).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
   CASE
   WHEN (NEW.my_string like '%patternXYZ%')
      THEN substring(NEW.my_string from '+pattern+') 
      ELSE '00'
   END AS data
FROM my_table;
```

Pattern should be the parameter for query.

Comment: The XYZ should be wild cards characters, this is the ones which can be anything.

Comment: So I guess this would work WHEN (NEW.my_string like '%pattern%'), but then I need the 3 next characters after pattern.

Comment: I've tried something like select SUBSTRING('patternXYZ' FROM '%pattern#"%#".%' for '#'); but it doesn't quick work, as I'm getting a bit more characters than simply XYZ.

Comment: @Michael Nielsen Actually i dont have the Postgre right here so cant say anything, will let you know soon

Comment: Seems to work, but is it optimised?: substring(substring('patternXYZ' from '%#"pattern___#"%' for '#') from 4)

Comment: Sorry, Seems to work, but is it optimised?: substring(substring('patternXYZ' from '%#"pattern___#"%' for '#') from 8)

Comment: try substring(NEW.my_string from 'pattern')

Comment: you can pass pattern as parameter

Comment: Seems to simply return the text "pattern", and not sure how to tell it to return the next 3 characters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142291/discussion-between-anurag-dadheech-and-michael-nielsen).